# Is there any substring function in helm chart yaml templates ?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can I substring a string like /com/app1/main to get the value of main in a HELM template ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use the [regexFind](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) function in helm

`regexFind "[^/]+$" "/com/app1/main"`

Will get the text following the last `/`

Answer (score 5):

The [sprig](http://masterminds.github.io/sprig/strings.html) library that Helm uses provides a `substr` function to return a sub-string.

Some other useful functions are `trunc` (truncate), `trim` and `regexFind`.

Answer (score 4):

Helm uses the sprig library to provide lots of data manipulation functions, have a look at [their docs](https://godoc.org/github.com/Masterminds/sprig). You can use the {{ base }} function to do what you want.